# Are there mantras that should be chanted by me for curing a person (not me)?

Tags: mantras, health

My teacher is in a very critical condition and i want to pray for his health,  but I don't know which mantras should be chanted at this time for healing him.

I know about the Mahamritunjaya mantra but how should it be chanted in order to benefit him? Please help.

Comment: I think you can make `Sankalpa` for the name of that person.

Comment: Chant Danvantri Mantra  or veeraraghava mantra.

Comment: there are many in the atharva veda. You should engage a priest of the atharva veda as to have the proper effect they must be pronounced correctly.

Comment: @Sree charan-- I have experienced in this site if I give the source also there will be negative votes and some comments give the source etc. That is why I am not giving answers but commenting. It enhances my knowledge and readers also. Biased principles.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan We should not fear for downvotes. If you are giving an answer, comments are not the right place. In this case, you have source too. Use answers for answering do not use comments.

Comment: @Sree charan -- I do not fear for downvotes. These are just numbers. + or -  the effort put go in vain. Hence I have answered in that way.

Comment: @Brij Raj Kishore A  long time ago "Pamula Narasayya"  was believed to heal even snake bites by a telephonic manthra message.

Comment: There is a procedure for it like @TriyugiNarayanMani has said. You can do japa for others but u have to the sankalpa accordingly. Even one can bath on behalf of others by taking appropriate sankalpas. But all these things are technical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mahamrityunjaya mantra is the best choice but it should be chanted in continuous manner accompanied by homam and abhishekam if problem is severe. Along with this, Sri Rudram should also chanted as much as possible. One has to visualize the energy of the mantra entering into the patient and healing him.

Mrityunjaya mantra is as follows,

[image]

As per Mantra-Mahodadhi Chapter 16,

[image]

Up to three nakshatras from the birth nakshatra, one has to perform homam with samidha (wood) of Guduchi to avoid diseases and untimely death. 46.47

Performing daily homam with Durva is said to be the best for avoiding untimely death and for fulfilling all the desired. 47-48

For curing fever, one has to perform homam with samidhA of apAmarga plant.

For fulfilling all desires, one has to perform homam with guduchi pieces soaked in milk for one month. 48-49

To sum up, homam should be done with guduchi and durva grass. Abhishekam should be done with articles like milk, yogurt, sugarcane juice, water, etc. 
For the homam one has to ideally do 10,000 oblations.

Answer (score 6):

Swami Vivekananda [Complete Works/Volume 5/Epistle - First Series/[IX_Sharat](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_5/Epistles_-_First_Series/IX_Sharat)]:

> Now I tell you a curious fact. **Whenever anyone of you is sick, let him himself or anyone of you visualise him in your mind, and mentally say and strongly imagine that he is all right. That will cure him quickly.** You can do it even without his knowledge, and even with thousands of miles between you. Remember it and do not be ill any more.

Surya Mantra can also cure diseases and give long life and health. According to Swami Sivananda[[Mantra Yoga Sadhana](http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=525)]:

> By constant repetition of the Mantra the Sadhaka imbibes the virtues and powers of the Deity that presides over the Mantra. Repetition of Surya Mantra bestows health, long life, vigour, vitality, Tejas or brilliance. It removes all diseases of the body and the diseases of the eye. No enemy can do any harm.

Comment: @chinmay--What you mentioned is strong positive thinking. Not any slokas mentioned as asked in the question.

Comment: **Whenever anyone of you is sick, let him himself or anyone of you visualise him in your mind, and mentally say and strongly imagine that he is all right. That will cure him quickly.**  Can this be achieved by anyone like us or only by those who have some Yogic powers? Did u try this urself on someone? Also regarding the Surya mantra- That is only about curing one's own diseases. How will it cure someone else's?

Comment: @Rickross Swami Vivekananda did say "when **anyone** of you..." so it all applies to all and not just yogis. As per my knowledge, there is no mantra which can cure other persons without thinking about them. I believe we have to visualise them in our mind and then chant mantra so that it can benefit them but then it brings us to Swami Vivekananda's method which doesn't involve any mantras and it also uses visualization technique.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Ok.. anyone of you may also mean to whom he is teaching that is his Yogi students. I have Rajayoga there whenever Swamiji says You it refers to those who are practicing Yoga and who are his students. IMO it can not be achieved without Yogic powers. **, there is no mantra which can cure other persons without thinking about them** No there are ways, you have to take sankalpa in the name of that person, then the whole fruit of the japa will go to that other person.

Comment: @Rickross No, the visualisation technique is for everyone. There is also a good book "Power of your subconscious mind" by Joseph Murphy, it contains pretty much the same thing, how to do healing, how to get things etc...
I'm not aware about Sankalpa so can't comment on that but I think Swamiji's method is the simplest of them all.

Answer (score 2):

Chant Dhanvantari Mantra.

Dhanvantari Mantra:

> Om namo Bhagavathe Vasudevaya Danvantaraye Amrutha Kalasa Hasthaya sarva aamaya vinachanaya triloka nathaya sri maha vishnavae namah

Source-- Tamil slokas compilation and Sambodh.us

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4m28Z5OyFk) for Dhanvantari mantra.

Just hear this video imbibe the mantra in your mind and recite near your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are countless healing mantras, which can be chanted in order to cure or give relief to someone near and dear to you.
These are Shabar, Vedic and other devotional mantras from the ramcharitmanas, which work effectively.
You can check the largest collection here - [best healing mantras](http://www.prophet666.com/2010/09/health-mantras.html)

Comment: Welcome! Good  to see you start answering. Although other links are acceptable but they don't make a genuine authority. It's highly recommended to cite scriptural sources.