# Which Hindu god should be prayed to in order to get good health?

Tags: gods, health

Which Hindu god (s) should be worshiped for achieving good health?

Comment: According to the verse given [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15619/which-scriptures-contain-the-verse-arogyam-bhaskarad-ichcheth) Surya or the Sun god.

Comment: You can worship Lord Rudra on Maha Mrityunjaya mantra

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19573

Comment: Sun ( Apollo).. Is the main

Comment: Most of the wrestlers in India use to worship Lord Hanuman. Even does Tuesday fast for him.

Comment: @Pradeep This is a good Q but it looks advice Q as of now..can "One of my neighbor is having health issues" be removed from Q to make it more general?

Comment: @YDS It wll still be a personal advice question if you remove that. The gist of the question doesn't change. There is already questions regarding whom to pray. But in these cases, we should not give false hopes that only mantras and stotras will help. That is the reason such questions are off-topic. They should see a doctor.

Comment: There are various suktas in Atharva-Veda like Dirghayu Sukta (for long life) ,Ayushya Suktam etc.Which indirectly prays for good health of indivisual person. The main deities of these suktas are Vishvadevas(various gods).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Scriptures contain the verse "Arogyam bhaskarad ichcheth"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15619/which-scriptures-contain-the-verse-arogyam-bhaskarad-ichcheth)

Comment: Dhata/Dhatri https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhatri or Gayatri

Answer (score 1):

Lord Shiva, also known as Vaidyanatheshwara, is to be worshiped for good health. In fact, offering milk to Shiva on the day of Pradosha is said to [bestow long life](http://arunachalagrace.blogspot.com/2012/10/signifance-of-pradosham.html).