# What is the name of the Yajna which is capable of curing diseases?

Tags: yajna, health

Tembe Swami or Vasudevananda Saraswati in his Dwisahastri Teeka says through the following procedures diseases can be cured.

> पूर्वजन्मकृतं पापं व्याधीरूपेण पीडते ।
>   तच्छान्तिरौषधैर्दानैर्जपहोमसुरार्चनैः ।।
>
> Sins commited in the previous births trouble in the form of
>   diseases (in this life). These diseases can be cured by medicines,
>   charity, japa, **yajna** and prayer of devatas.

I never knew that there are Yajnas which are capable of curing diseases before reading this. I would like to know the name of the Yajna which can cure diseases.

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29629/which-hindu-god-should-be-prayed-to-in-order-to-get-good-health