How can one get rid of all the diseases, Illnesses?
Hey it's my first question on this site I hope I will get a reply soon.
So my questions.

Is there any way to get rid of all the diseases, illness and sickness like seasonal cold, influenza virus and etc?

I've heard that chanting mahamrityunjay mantra gets rid of all illnesses and diseases is it true?


I'd appreciate it if you could please provide some text where it is said so.
I do not have any diseases or illnesses at all, thanks to God. But when I see ill people I not only feel bad for them, I also feel afraid, i wish to never get ill like that so to avoid all that I'm seeking answers to my questions.
Thanks.
Jai Ram.

In my understanding, it is not possible to get rid of karma phala of prArabdha karma. Not even God can stop that. As for non-prArabdha karma - only jnAna of brahman can destroy non-prArabdha karmas and mantras may be able to indirectly help in attaining jnAna in the long term. But attaining jnAna is very very difficult. Long story short, there is no way to get rid of diseases, illnesses. Of course, as I said, this is my understanding.

One can manage health through Yoga and Ayurveda. But ALL diseases for a body that is temporary and aging is not possible unless you find the fountain of youth

Please see this question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30112/what-is-the-name-of-the-yajna-which-is-capable-of-curing-diseases

As it is said, "मृत्युंजय महादेव त्राहिमां शरणागतम्।
जन्ममृत्युजराव्याधी पीडितं कर्मबन्धनैः॥". So the disease is part of our karma and one can pray to seek help, but best thing is to take medical advise.

!!DO NOT CHANT MAHAMRITYUNJAY WITHOUT DIKSHA!!
The KulArnava Tantram says
Pushtake likhitAnmantrAn vilokya prajapanti ye |
BrahmahatyAsamam teshAm pAtakam parikirtitam ||
Meaning
One, who chants mantras by seeing them from books [that is not obtained duely from a sampradaya Guru] commits, thereby, sin as grave as BrahmahatyA (Brahminicide).
KulArnava Tantram, UlAsaha 5, Verse 22.
You should go for guru dikha first
But you can do naam jaap without initiation like Radha, Ram, Krishna, Hari
We get diseases because of our prarabdha but naam japa can change and even erase our prabdha (glory of Hari name)

